# On image mouseover zoom

Tags: jquery

Here is my jQuery code..

```
 $('img').live('mouseenter',function()
          {  
              $(this).addClass('shown');
              $('.shown').animate({width: '+=50',height: '+=50'})
          });

 $('img').live('mouseleave',function()
          {
              $(this).removeClass('shown');
              $(this).addClass('reset');
               $('.reset').animate({width: '-=50',height: '-=50'})
          });
```

It is removing the image after some mouse enters.. Please help me..

Comment: [It doesn't do that for me](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/nYpAu/).

Comment: are you just zooming and shrinking? or do the classes 'shown' and 'reset' have other effects on them?  if they don't, you do not need to add/remove the classes, just animate.  use .stop with your animate also.

Comment: Hi, I have done debugging the code.. Here is the code, thanks @rkw..                                                             $('img').live('mouseenter',function()
              {  
                  $(this).animate({width: '+=50',height: '+=50'})
                  $(this).addClass('y');   
              });
$('.y').live('mouseleave',function()
             {
                 $(this).animate({width: '-=50',height: '-=50'})
             });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making selection of the image to animate more complicated than it needs to be:

```
$('img').hover(
    function () { 
        $(this).animate({width: '+=50', height: '+=50'});
    },
    function () {
        $(this).animate({width: '-=50', height: '-=50'});
    });
```