# What determines margin change amount for image pop up in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

In another question of stackoverflow:
[on Hover Image zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798358/on-hover-image-zoom)

They tell you how to make an image pop up when hovered over. The answer was given in this jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/uCtHh/1/

In the code the image size is `50px` and changes to `100px` when hovered.
However the negative margin given on hover is only -20px.

Shouldn't it be -50px as the the size of the image goes up by 50?

Comment: image change is 50 px bt you have to concern that it is change 25px each side from its mid .:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically whoever wrote the jsfiddle wanted it to look like the picture was expanding out from the middle. Intuitively this would mean that the left and top margins should be -25px. This is because each dimension grows by 50px, but you want it to expand out equally from the center, so each side should be half of the absolute amount of dimensional growth (i.e. 25px) farther out from where it started.

The reason it's -20px in the jsfiddle is because the image margin is already 5px.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it to see what happens when you change the margin to -50px.

When the margin left is changed to -50px, a large part of the right picture will be above the left one. the left margin determine how much the distance will be between picture and the left side of the page or the item from the left. so if you don't want that the picture will be above the left picture, you can even set this to 10px.

Comment: Thank you.
So from what point to what point will the margin be calculated.
will the margin be calculated from the left of the parent to the **center** of the image,
or will the margin be calculated from the left of the parent to the **outer border** of the image?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your page has width 700px.And your image width is 100px(say).
midpoint of the page is at 350px and midpoint of the image is 50px.
now to have your right margin so that your image will be at middle ??
calculate

- **page width:350 ***to be at middle*
- **imagewidth 50 ***to be middle*
- **this 50 px counts on both side of margin**
- since your page has 350px and image has 25 px. Substract pagewidth-imageWidth i.e**350-25 will be your margin

---

my answer looks bulky i am sorry . Its looks simple but its tricky one .

**

Answer (score 1):

When hovered, the image will expand 25px to the left (margin changes from +5px to -20px) and 25px to the right (because of the size of the image: 100px new image size - 50px old image size - 25px left margin). Since the image has been expanded equally to the left and right it will look centered.

If you put -50px on the other hand, then it will expend 55px to the left and -5px to the right so it will look like it has been moved to the left - which is not requested behavior.